# Writing a migration from non a non Drupal site

Tags: 7, database, migrations

How can I translate this in a migrate query?

```
SELECT t.name FROM tags t 
    join tag_types tt on (tt.id = 3)
    join story_tags stg on (stg.tag_id = t.id) WHERE story_id = $row_id'
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
->select('story_tags', 'tags')
->fields('tags', array('tag_id'))
->leftJoin('tag_types', 'tt', '(tt.id = tag.tag_type_id)')
->condition('tag_type_id', '3', '=' )
->condition('story_id', $row->id, '=')
->execute()
->fetchCol();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try like follows
`$query = db_select('tags', 't');
$query->fields('t', array('name'));
$query->innerJoin('tag_types', 'tt', 'tt.id = 3');
$query->innerJoin('story_tags', 'stg', 'stg.tag_id = t.id');
$query->condition('story_id', '');
$result = $query->execute();`

Comment: Thanks. New to all of this an can't find a good link with details/explanation on how to write the queries.

Comment: no :( . Have a blank page on the migrate webpage. trying to figure out where the error is.

Comment: You use `tag.tag_type_id`, but the alias for the table is _tags_. (See the `select('story_tags', 'tags')` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the answer you are looking for, as it is not [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate), but when I did this a couple years ago for a large client this is how I did it.

First, I set up the [Feed Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/feed_import) module and a [map of column names to desired fields](https://www.isovera.com/blog/using-feeds-module-bulk-import-drupal-7).  Second, on the various non-drupal sites that I was migrating to a single drupal install I [exported the data to csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format) paying careful attention to the column aliases so they matched the map.  Also, as it totalled a lot of rows, I broke it into several files to run them in batches.  Using an anchored feed import, I was able to run them in batches and subsets of data, to purge and re-import any set as needed, and to group all the difficult international names together by sorting my csv files.

It took a day for every 10,000 nodes I imported.

Comment: That's interesting because I would like to start using Feed Import. but the speed benchmark you've stated gives me pause. With crazy usage of `mtm-migrate` from the Migrate addons you can do 10000+ inserts easily in under 5 minutes.

Comment: Yeah, it was a not-fun week of imports.  The import was made more difficult by the use of field collections.  I had to add a hidden hash field to the main node and then use the GUID option with the hash on the field collection to make the import work, but fortunately mysql has the ability to md5 hash things as a separate column.  But it worked, I was able to aggregate the data from a half dozen servers into one drupal site with Organic Groups keeping the data partitioned.  The migrate module is the recommended route by many of the large names in the drupal field, this is another option.

Comment: Again, this was a couple years ago and things continue to improve.

Comment: @tenken it looks like kiamlaluno found your migrate typo